# Defining addition operation in symmetric group.

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic, symmetric-groups

We know that every integer $n\in\Bbb Z$ has an unique prime decomposition $$n=p_1\cdot\dots\cdot p_r$$ where $r$ is number of prime factors $p_i$ of $n$.

We know that every member $\sigma\in S_n$ has an unique cycle decomposition $$\sigma=c_1\cdot\dots\cdot c_r$$ where $r$ is number of cycle factors $c_i$ of $\sigma$.

Can we define addition of $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$?

Comment: The similarity is superficial. There's no such thing as a prime element of a group, and the factorization into cycles is only interesting because it makes it easier to work with the group.

Comment: @MattSamuel Ok only asking for additivity.

Comment: You can add group elements in the [group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring), but I'm not sure that's the sort of thing you're after.